# Fortran can't read from file

Tags: fortran

I am trying to read multiple variables from a txt file I created using Fortran. The number of lines of the file was random as well as the numbers written on each line.

The file looks something like this:

```
1061    2.5   5.0    7.5    3.5
1062    9.0   2.5   10.0    7.5
```

Then I open the file on a separate Fortran program and try to read from it.

My code looked something like this, `a` is an `integer`, while `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` are all real values:

```
    open(10,file='data.txt',form='unformatted')
    do
        read(10,*,iostat=st) a,b,c,d,e
        if(st==-1) exit 
        f=a+b+c+d+e
    end do
```

When I try to run the program, than a runtime error appears telling me that I am referring on undefined variables and when I try to run the debugger, the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` stay undefined even after the read command.

Comment: Can you please add error trace here, that will help other users to understand your problem better.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try taking off the `iostat` and see if there is a run-time error - my guess is that there is.

Comment: Please [edit] question to include the definition of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`.

Comment: To slightly extend @SteveLionel 's comment iostat is guaranteed to be 0 on success and another value (not necessarily -1) if something went wrong. Checking it to be -1 almost certainly doesn't catch all the possible errors, and if an error occurred a, b, c, d and e will be undefined.

Comment: ok so error says reference to undifined variable, array element or function result(/UNDEF) at adress 401824 at the line f=a+b+c+d+e.

Comment: i use the iostat so that the do command will stop when there is nothing else to read

Comment: The perpose of my read command is to have: a=1061,b=2.5,c=5.0,d=7.5,e=3.5 and so on for the next line then i want to use these variables in some calqulations.

Comment: Change your test to `if (st /= 0) exit`.  `st` is not guaranteed to be `-1`.  Change your read statement to `read(10,*,iostat=st,end=10)` and add a statement label `10` to first statement after the do-loop.

Comment: ok so chganging my if to (st/=0) did stop the run time error however now the programm exits the do command before even completing the first loop....

Comment: So please follow @SteveLionel his advise and provide a MWE! otherwise it will stay staring into a crystal ball.

Comment: Add `character(len=80) msg` to your declarations.  You do have everything properly declared, right?  Then add `iomsg=msg` to the read statement and then print out the `msg`.  If the code is not getting past the first line, then this suggests you have an unprintable character in the first line causing a short read.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that your file is a formatted file (in fact you use `*` as format). However you define it as `'unformatted'` in the `open` statement. Try to set

```
form='formatted'
```

in your `open` statement or just omit the `form=` clause, since the default is formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Just summarizing the comments and the existing answer, you should remove the
`'unformatted'` keyword in the open statement, as `fortran` reads text files
as your `data.txt` as formatted one by default.

Assuming that your text file might look like this:

```
1061    2.5   5.0    7.5    3.5
1062    9.0   2.5   10.0    7.5
1063    4.0   3.1    3.2    5  
1064    2.1   1.9  *****    7.8
1065    1.0   4.0   10.0    3.5
1066    4.4   1.9    2.5
1067    6.7   8.8   10.9   12.0
```

then you should handle the different formatting errors following this
minimal example:

```
program FileIO
implicit none
character(256) :: line
character(80)  :: msg
integer :: a,st
real :: b,c,d,e,f

open(10,file='data.txt')
do
    write(*,'(A)') '------------------------------------------------------------'
    read(10,'(A)',iostat=st) line                 ! Buffer input in line
    write(*,'(A)') 'Reading of line '//trim(line)
    if (st < 0) then                              ! End of file or end of record
        exit
    else
        read(line,*,iostat=st,iomsg=msg) a,b,c,d,e
        write(*,'(A)') 'IO-message is: '//trim(msg)
        if (st == 0) then                         ! Read one line successfully
            write(*,'(A)') 'Line successfully read: '//trim(line)
            f=a+b+c+d+e                           ! Calculate result
        else
            write(*,'(A)') 'IO-error occured in line: '//trim(line)
            f=0
        endif
    endif
end do
close(10)

end program FileIO
```

A negative result for `iostat` indicates an end of file or end of record event. A positive result for `iostat` indicates a run-time error message, see e.g. for [Intel Fortran](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-list-of-run-time-error-messages#BAD476FE-3A8C-48AA-B611-3400DC2A7EDB).

This should be handled by an `if` condition.

I recommend you to buffer the file input in a character variable, e.g. `line`.
It helps you to write the error generating line back to a log file or standard
output.

The minimal example generates this output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Reading of line 1061    2.5   5.0    7.5    3.5
IO-message is:                                                                  
Line successfully read: 1061    2.5   5.0    7.5    3.5
------------------------------------------------------------
Reading of line 1062    9.0   2.5   10.0    7.5
IO-message is:                                                                  
Line successfully read: 1062    9.0   2.5   10.0    7.5
------------------------------------------------------------
Reading of line 1063    4.0   3.1    3.2    5
IO-message is:                                                                  
Line successfully read: 1063    4.0   3.1    3.2    5
------------------------------------------------------------
Reading of line 1064    2.1   1.9  *****    7.8
IO-message is: list-directed I/O syntax error, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Read
IO-error occured in line: 1064    2.1   1.9  *****    7.8
------------------------------------------------------------
Reading of line 1065    1.0   4.0   10.0    3.5
IO-message is: list-directed I/O syntax error, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Read
Line successfully read: 1065    1.0   4.0   10.0    3.5
------------------------------------------------------------
Reading of line 1066    4.4   1.9    2.5
IO-message is: end-of-file during read, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Read
IO-error occured in line: 1066    4.4   1.9    2.5
------------------------------------------------------------
Reading of line 1067    6.7   8.8   10.9   12.0
IO-message is: end-of-file during read, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Read
Line successfully read: 1067    6.7   8.8   10.9   12.0
------------------------------------------------------------
Reading of line 1067    6.7   8.8   10.9   12.0
```

The list-directed reading of line 1063 works fine, even if the number `5` is
given as integer to the real variable `e`. The formatting error `*****` of line
1064 is detected correctly as well as the missing number in line 1066.

Please have a look to the Intel Fortran help regarding [list-directed reading](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-rules-for-list-directed-sequential-read-statements#C0ADB840-A281-48E7-B0C8-AEFD987952D3),
if you need more information.

Hope it helps.